# Using structures and pointer arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, new-operator

I am trying to write a pointer array to structs in C++. My main goal is to be able to dynamically add pointers to the array. I am having trouble with the synthax

```
  struct items
  {
    int member1;
    int member2;
  };

  int N=5;
  items **ptr=new item *[N]; // This is a ptr to an array of ptr's. Each ptr 
                             // in this array needs to point to an items struct.
```

My question is how to write in the struct's objects from this point on. I know I need to create them first but I don't have any idea how to do that.

Comment: The ideal solution is probably a `std::vector<item>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<item>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating only an array of pointers of `item *`, you'll need to allocate the memory for each `item` also, e.g.:

```
struct item // naming it 'items' might be confusing, and was used inconsistently
            // in your code sample
{
    int member1;
    int member2;
};

int N=5;
item **ptr=new item *[N];

for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    ptr[i] = new item();
}
```

Accessing your structure members looks like this:

```
ptr[2]->member1 = 42; // Sets member1 of the 3rd item element to 42
```

**Note** that you'll need to free the allocated memory somewhere as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    delete ptr[i];
}
delete [] ptr;
```

**I general for [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)** you'd be better off using a c++ standard container like:

```
#include <vector>

int N = 5;
std::vector<item> myItems;
myItems.resize(N,item());

myItems[2].member1 = 42; // Sets member1 of the 3rd item element to 42
```

which would do all the memory management for you internally.
If you're using [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and do not need dynamically sized arrays you can even avoid heap allocated memory at all using `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

std::array<item,5> myItems; // Size is fixed to 5, you can't use a variable here

myItems[2].member1 = 42; // Sets member1 of the 3rd item element to 42
```

Comment: It's working. What is the advantage in using vectors instead of what I did? I am new to C++ and have not studied about vectors yet.

Comment: And also, you wrote that accessing structure members is done with:ptr[2]->member1 = 42;. What is its equivalent? for ex: *(ptr[2]).id?

Comment: Don't know what exactly you mean with _'What is its equivalent'_, but I'd say `*(ptr[2]).member1` (there's no field `id` introduced anywhere). What concerns the advantages of using standard containers, it's clearly written in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the response! As for the field "id" I meant member1. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can add objects to your array by `ptr[i] = new items()`. And you can access data in `items** ptr` by `ptr[i]->member1`. But I'll strongly recommend using stl containers and smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to finish the allocation step.

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  ptr[i]=new items;
```

Then you can access the array using e.g.:

```
ptr[0]->member1=123;
```